# Change the CSS of a multiple div class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to define a style for:

```html
<div class="simplequiz result" style="float: left; margin: 0 30px 30px 0; text-align: center; max-width: 80px;"><span class="simplequiz result_quiz_name" style="font-size: smaller;">Análise</span><br><br><span class="simplequiz result_total" style="font-size: large;">1/2 (50%)</span></div>
```

So, after a lot of searching in stack overflow, I got this CSS:

```
.simplequiz.result{
    float:none;
    max-width:500px !important;
    text-align:left;
}
```

But the style is totally unchanged!

My CSS skills are just too basic, can anyone help?

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Well, as you may see in the html code, the styling is not what I want (see the css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline styles have priority over external CSS rules, that's why nothing changes. What you can do is to add `!important` to all your settings, although this is something that's only recommended in situtations where nothing else is possible.

```
.simplequiz.result{
    float:none !important;
    max-width:500px !important;
    text-align:left !important;
}
```